# Difference of elements of 1 unsorted array within given interval

Tags: arrays, algorithm

Let as assume that we have an unsorted array which is composed of integers.We also have 2 given integers ,L and M. Our task is to compute the number of all pairs of (i,j) that hold the following property : L<=A[j]-A[i]<=M.

Apart from the obvious brute force algorithm that checks all possible pairs ( O(n^2) complexity ) ,is there a faster way to solve this problem?

Comment: For worst case, your output size itself is `O(n^2)`. Consider the array `[1,1,1,1,1,1...,1]`, with `L=M=0`. You need to output all pairs, and that's quadric. That said, you might be able to do it in `O(f(n) + m)` where `m` is the output size and `f(n)` is in `o(n^2)` (small o notation here), if that helps I can try to think of something.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you just need to count the number of distinct pairs because otherwise you cannot hope for a better worst case complexity than O(n^2).

You can sort the array in O(nlogn) time keeping track of the original array indices.

Then just scan the sorted array and maintain two pointers such that all the elements between the indices that they point to have an absolute difference in the range `[L, M]`. This part can be done in linear time.

Comment: `This part can be done in linear time.`, not trivially (I cannot see a way to do it trvially at least). Consider [1,2,3,4,...,n] with `L=0,M=k>1` you will need to go back and forth with both pointers (to get for example (1,4) and then back (2,3), causing it to be quadric - unless you have some trick to prevent it and give a hard cap on the number of times going back.

Comment: @amit, say L = 0, M = 4. you make pointer lo, hi point to 1, and keep incrementing hi till A[hi]-A[lo] <= 4. Update totalCount+= 4C2.  Now increment lo and again check upto what point hi can go, say new lo = 2, hi = 8. Update totalCount += (6C2 - 2C2) because 2C2 have already been counted. (missing anything?)

Comment: Think I got you. Need a few minutes to think about it, but looks good to me.+1, and thanks for explaining.

Comment: The answer seems to be useful but to be honest, I am not a veteran of algorithms .Could you please provide more details ?

Answer (score 0):

Finding the number of such pairs can be done in `O(nlogn)` by maintaining an **[order statistics trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic_tree)**.

```
for each element x:
  find x-L (or closest and higher element) in the tree. Let its index be i1.
  finx x-M (or closest and smaller element) in the tree. Let its index be i2.
  element x is part of i2-i1+1 pairs where x is the higher from the prefix of the array.
  add this value to the sum.
  Repeat for x+L,x+M
  add x to the tree.
```

**This is `O(nlogn)`**, each addition and search is `O(logn)`. This is done `n` times, so total of `O(nlogn)`.

---

**Lower bound complexity:** It cannot be done better than `O(nlogn)` under algebraic tree model, since doing so will allow solving [element distinctness problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Element_distinctness_problem) in `Omega(nlogn)`, which is known to be impossible.

Thus, the problem is `Omega(nlogn)` under this model.